# Why does it change on :hover

Tags: css

I'm making a menu with floating menu items.

What I want is to always have 10 px padding in top, on hover and not hovering.

My HTML:

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <div class="menuitem">
        Home
    </div>  

    <div class="menuitem">
        Item2
    </div>

    <div class="menuitem">
        Item3
    </div>

    <div class="menuitem">
        Item4
    </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#menu
{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#B89470;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.menuitem
{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:10px;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;

}

.menuitem:hover
{   
    background-color:#abca9e;
}
```

So I have made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6w5kz/).

But for some reasing the padding is only showing while :hover is active.

But I have set the padding in

**.menuitemn**

and not in

**.menuitem:hover**

so why isn't there any padding when hover isn't active?

Comment: No, [the padding is always there](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6w5kz/2/). It's just that you can't see it, until you change the colour.

Comment: check the fiddle (im using chrome) it isnt

Comment: Yes, it *is* (check the link I posted, I'm *also* using Chrome).

Comment: sorry So it is because there isnt any color in the menuitem right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `padding-top: 10px;` is adding 10px to the height of the `menuitem` making it `60px` in height. Yet the `#menu` still remains at `50px` with an overlap of `10px`. I changed the height of `#menu` to show you.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/6w5kz/1/

```
height:60px;
```

Comment: The reason it isn't visible not on hover is because the background is applied to `#menu` and not `menuitem`

Comment: If you assign the initial background to `menuitem` you will see what i mean DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/6w5kz/4/

Comment: This is the most complete solution. hiding overflow would hide the problem and could effect other elements.

Comment: +1 this is the best solution. However, I just wanted to give another possible one (:

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the proposed ones would be to add:

```
#menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

The problem is that the child `.menuitem` is bigger than the `#menu`, so it overflows it. This happens because of the [box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/), which I really recommend you to read. So there are several ways to solve it, one is the one I pointed out, other is @Vector's and another is not setting the height of `#menu` so it's as high as needed.

I've also added `cursor: pointer;` when you hover the `.menuitem` to show properly that it's a clickable item.

> http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/6w5kz/3/